# SVN 1.8.5 marks entire files as conflicted

Tags: svn, branching-and-merging

I am having trunk and one branch. I have updates in both and I want to merge trunk changes to branch. And all files merges correcty, but one is marked as conflict. The problem is that I cant merge them because svn marks all lines as different. How can I solve this?

svn diff on that file in trunk and branch also shows all file lines as different.

My server svn version: `svnserve, version 1.8.5 (r1542147)
   compiled Jan 13 2014, 03:38:23 on i486-pc-linux-gnu`

My client svn version: `svn, version 1.8.5 (r1542147)
   compiled Dec  2 2013, 16:38:04 on i686-pc-linux-gnu`

Comment: Have you changed the `svn:eol-style` property on one of the versions? If you have, subversion often considers both files to be different. Try to perform the same change on the other version as well before you merge.

Comment: @Lindydancer That was my first thought, but I have not changed eol-style and didn't used different os, so I didn't checked it. But when I run diff with -x "--ignore-eol-style" everything works as expected. So you are righ. This is eol problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was EOL problem. I did not changed svn:eol-style or used different os, that is why I didn't checked it before. But using `svn merge ^/trunk -x "-w --ignore-eol-style"` solved my problem (Thanks to @Lindydancer).

Comment: Good that you solved it. I was not aware of the --ignore-eol-style options so I learned something new here too!